# reinitialize random to be reinitialized

Tags: zsh, random

Printing the `$RANDOM` variable in `zsh` is giving me the same result if I don't use it in another context. It's like the shell has a cache of command outputs or variable values so I can't have the new value. I am, running this:

```
zsh $ printf \\$(printf "%o" $(( $RANDOM % 123)))\\$(printf "%o" $(( $RANDOM % 123)))
```

It's two times the same `$RANDOM` result and in different successive runs, I still get the same result as the first run.

Still get the exact same behaviour `printf \\$(printf "%o" $(( $(echo $RANDOM) % 123)))\\$(printf "%o" $(( $(echo $RANDOM) % 123)))`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a property of `zsh`. See also `man zshparam` on `RANDOM`:

> The  values  of RANDOM form an intentionally-repeatable pseudo-random
> sequence; subshells that reference RANDOM will  result  in  identical
> pseudo-random  values  unless  the  value  of RANDOM is referenced or
> seeded in the parent shell in between subshell invocations.

You're evaluating `$RANDOM` inside subshells, so this is the expected result:

```
$ RANDOM=123
$ echo $(echo $RANDOM) $(echo $RANDOM) $(echo $RANDOM)
17313 17313 17313
```

Same command in bash or busybox ash:

```
$ echo $(echo $RANDOM) $(echo $RANDOM) $(echo $RANDOM)
12554 22752 18907
```

Different shell, different behavior.

---

Different example in `zsh`:

```
$ RANDOM=123
$ echo $RANDOM $(echo $RANDOM) $RANDOM $(echo $RANDOM) $RANDOM    
17313 7829 7829 9329 9329
```

Whenever the parent shell uses `$RANDOM`, the subshells that follow will give the next number in the pseudo-random sequence. But since the subshell does not affect the parent shell, the numbers are repeated when the parent shell uses `$RANDOM` again.

Comment: This reply to "Why do I have same values?", not to "How to get different values?". But your reply is well explained, enlightening and much appreciated

Comment: @aaa Basically, one of… don't use $RANDOM, don't use subshells, don't use zsh, don't use shellscripts, ;-) … unless zsh offers an easy way to auto-reseed. Sure you could reseed it yourself, just grab a random number from /dev/urandom to use as seed, plenty of ways to do that... but then you could just use that number directly, so what you still need $RANDOM for? Certainly not worth it for a subshell that uses $RANDOM only once…

Comment: Subshells not updating the parent shell's random seed seems like a natural consequence of implementing via `fork`.  I guess `zsh` does have to delay expansion of `$RANDOM` so it only happens in the child, though, not when the initial parse sees an unquoted `$RANDOM`; that's presumably what the other shells are doing.

Comment: This is all because of the sensibilities of certain programmers to make things more cryptic for certain convenience sake -- it is grossly overdocumented where it isn't needed with tiny nuggets of actual truth inside. Zsh has a tendency to randomly remark on these little details throughout its documentation . So, unless you read and retained ALL the ZSH manual, little things like this can and will  trip you up, over and over again.  You might want to cache (and check) your random numbers ahead of time to prevent the same problem from "repeating" in the future (terrible pun I know).

Answer (score 3):

You'll get the same `$RANDOM` value from two subshells, but here you don't need subshells.

To get the character corresponding to a given value (even arithmetic expression), you can use the `#` parameter expansion flag:

```
$ (){ printf %s ${(#)argv}; } RANDOM%123 RANDOM%123
KU
```

Here with that flag applied to arguments of an anonymous function.

Even with `printf`, you don't need to spawn subshells:

```
$ printf -v var '\\%o' RANDOM%123 RANDOM%123
$ print $var
D#
```

Beware that in multibyte locales, the `#` parameter expansion flag will give you the character that corresponds to the wchar_t value. On GNU systems, that's Unicode code point.

```
$ () { print ${(#)1}; } 128039
```

To just get the raw byte for numbers from 0 to 255, you'd need `set +o multibyte`. A `print_raw_bytes` function could be written:

```
print_raw_bytes() {
  set -o localoptions +o multibyte
  printf %s ${(#)argv}
}
```

```
$ print_raw_bytes 0 128 255 | hexdump -C
00000000  00 80 ff                                          |...|
00000003
```

---

Also note that `$RANDOM` gives you a pseudo-random number between 0 and 32767 which is 123 ✕ 266 + 49. So values from 50 to 122 have a slightly lower probability of occurrence.

As an alternative to `$RANDOM` you can use the `rand48()` math function (`$(( int(rand48() * 123) ))`). Like `$RANDOM`, it's a deterministic pseudo-random generator, so invocations that share the same seed like two subshells started one after the other will yield the same result.

For a truly random number, you could get it off `/dev/urandom`:

For instance for a 32 bit integer one as a math function:

```
random() {
  set -o localoptions +o multibyte
  local bytes
  IFS= read -rk4 -u0 bytes < /dev/urandom || return
  ()(( #1 << 24 | #2 << 16 | #3 << 8 | #4 )) ${(s[])bytes}
}
functions -M random 0 0
```

```
$ (echo $RANDOM $(( random() ))); (echo $RANDOM $(( random() )))
3552 4059454208
3552 461504713
```